# findViewById not resolved

Tags: android, view, find

I have this piece of code in a fragment but it says **cannot resolve method findViewById**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_detail, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you need to give the root view: fragmentLayout.findViewById(..);

Comment: use fragmentLayout.findViewById();

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.fab);
```